# Program flow dependant on a time window

Tags: python-3.x

```
from gpiozero import Button, LED 
from time import time, sleep 
from random import randint

led = LED(17) btn = Button(27)

while True:

    btn.wait_for_release()
    start = time()
    led.on()
    btn.wait_for_press()
    end = time()
    led.off()


print(end-start, 'seconds')
```

I want to upgrade this include a time window for the button press:

- If the button is pressed in this time window (e.g. 5 minutes) the program stops.
- If the button has not been pressed when the time window expires the program continues and executes a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_boards.html?highlight=wait_for_press#gpiozero.ButtonBoard.wait_for_press):

`wait_for_press(timeout=None)`

> Parameters:   timeout (float) – Number of seconds to wait before
>   proceeding. If this is None (the default), then wait indefinitely
>   until the device is active.

This means that you can wait for a specific `timeout`, like so:

```
while True:

    btn.wait_for_release()
    start = time()
    led.on()
    btn.wait_for_press(5*60) # wait 5 minutes
    end = time()
    led.off()
```

Comment: Thanks It's workiing! now I'm trying to execute a code that sends notifications to my phone if button is not pressed within 5 mins. what do you think is the best way to do that ? is using a 'if' statement good?

Comment: sure, an `if` statement will suffice.